# Trying to make a POST request using Keycloak. Says CSRF token is missing

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, oauth-2.0, keycloak, spring-cloud-gateway

I've setup a Keycloak server using a docker-compose file:

```
  auth-db:
    image: postgres:13.5
    environment:
        POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
        POSTGRES_USER: my_admin
        POSTGRES_PASSWORd: my_password
        POSTGRES_DB: keycloak_db
    ports:
        - '5432:5432'
  keycloak:
   image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:legacy
   environment:
     DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
     DB_ADDR: auth-db


     DB_SCHEMA: public
     DB_DATABASE: keycloak_db
     DB_USER: my_admin
     DB_PASSWORD: my_password
     KEYCLOAK_USER: kc_admin
     KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: kc_password
   ports:
     - '8080:8080'
   depends_on:
     - auth-db
```

I've connected my gateway like so -

```
server:
  port: 8082
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: reactive
  application:
    name: GATEWAY-SERVICE
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
       - id: product-service
         uri: http://product-service:8081/products
         predicates:
           Path=/products/**
         filters:
           TokenRelay=
       - id: resource-service
         uri: http://resource-service:8083/message
         predicates:
           Path=/message/**
         filters:
           TokenRelay=

  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
             gateway:
              provider: my-provider
              client-id: my_client
              client-secret: tY0eCQyWnpqPKftcEP0S5T3ZXbETsji3
              authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
              redirect-uri: "http://gateway-service:8082/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
        provider:
          my-provider:
            issuer-uri: http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/my_realm


eureka:
  client:
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    register-with-eureka: true
  instance:
    health-check-url: /health
    hostname: gateway-service
    prefer-ip-address: true
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.cloud: TRACE
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
```

Filter Chain example in my product-service

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {


    private final RSAPublicKey key;
    private final JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

    public SecurityConfig(JwtDecoder jwtDecoder, RSAPublicKey key) {
        this.key=key;
        this.jwtDecoder=jwtDecoder;
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http   .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/**")
                        .hasAnyAuthority("SCOPE_message.read, SCOPE_message.write")



                )
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2)-> oauth2.jwt((jwt) ->
                                jwt
                                        .decoder(jwtDecoder())
                        )
                );
        return http.build();
    }


    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(this.key).build();
    }
}
```

application.yml for my product-service.

```
server:
  port: 8081
spring:
  application:
    name: product-service
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://product-db:3307/PRODUCT_DB
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: user
    password: user

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/my_realm
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
    hostname: product-service
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
```

My other microservices are configured as resource servers, and are able to perform GET requests just fine. However, if I try a POST request on Postman, I receive -
403 Forbidden -
"An expected CSRF token cannot be found"

I have disabled csrf in my Security Filters for every microservice, including the gateway.
Is there something I can configure in Keycloak in order to allow this?
Any ideas what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing the java conf for all your apps, and we have very little info on your front-end and the exact error logs, so it's hard to tell where your problem comes from...

You should not (like really not) disable CSRF protection on the gateway: it is configured as an OAuth2 client => request to the gateway are secured with sessions and are exposed to CSRF attacks.

CSRF protection can be disabled on resource servers (your "product" and "resource" services), but it should be disabled there only.

If the front-end uses a Javascript based framework (Angular, React, Vue, etc.), the gateway should be configured with filter to set a CSRF cookie with `http-only=false`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will edit it with more information. I'll also look into setting the cookie in the filter. I've never worked with CSRF tokens before, and I thought that by using Keycloak as the authentication I wouldn't need them.